# I cannot install OPM package

Tags: r

/var/folders/z1/0jjps00n14q5qw4__zbsh7b80000gn/T//RtmpzCOfFK/downloaded_packages > install.packages("~/Downloads/opm_1.2.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source") ERROR: dependencies ‘hwriter’, ‘plotrix’, ‘Ckmeans.1d.dp’, ‘pkgutils’, ‘yaml’, ‘grofit’, ‘rjson’, ‘DBI’ are not available for package ‘opm’ * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/opm’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘/Users/apple/Downloads/opm_1.2.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Why aren't you installing from CRAN (ie `install.packages("opm")`)? The error message seems pretty clear, you don't have the necessary dependencies installed. If you would have installed from a CRAN mirror, they could have been downloaded automatically. If you want to install them manually from a gz file, you'll have to do that for each of the packages listed in the error message (and for whatever dependencies they may have).

Answer (score 0):

As noted, you have to install the dependencies.  All of those except 'pkgutils' are current in CRAN.  'pkgutils' is in the archive package setting.  Once you install these, you're good to load 'opm' from the local archive file.